# Refer to an outer instance from an XBL component in Orbeon

Tags: orbeon, xforms, xbl

I am making my own component and within it I want to set value of an outer instance. For example, my main form has:

```
<xf:model id="fr-form-model" xxf:expose-xpath-types="true">
    <!-- Main instance -->
    <xf:instance id="fr-form-instance">
        <form>
            <section-1>
                <myControl/>
            </section-1>
        </form>
    </xf:instance>
    ...
```

and inside `myControl.xbl` I have:

```
<xf:setvalue
  model="fr-form-model"
  ref="instance('fr-form-instance')/form/section-1/myControl"
  value="'myValue'" />
```

but unfortunately it doesn't see `fr-form-model` ("Reference to non-existing model id: fr-form-model") which is understandable, because the component is encapsulated and cannot see outer elements. How can I refer to the outer instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write to the control binding with `xxf:binding()` (see also [gist](https://gist.github.com/ebruchez/11378574)):

```
<xh:html
        xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
        xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
        xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner">
    <xh:head>
        <xf:model>
            <xf:instance>
                <value/>
            </xf:instance>
        </xf:model>
        <xbl:xbl xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl" xmlns:xxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl">
            <xbl:binding id="fr-gaga" element="fr|gaga" xxbl:mode="binding">
                <xbl:template>
                    <xf:trigger>
                        <xf:label>Set value</xf:label>
                        <xf:setvalue event="DOMActivate" ref="xxf:binding('fr-gaga')" value="42"/>
                    </xf:trigger>
                </xbl:template>
            </xbl:binding>
        </xbl:xbl>
    </xh:head>
    <xh:body>
        <fr:gaga ref="instance()"/>
        <xf:output value="instance()"/>
    </xh:body>
</xh:html>
```

Otherwise, the quick and dirty way is to use the `xxf:instance()` function instead. It has visibility through the boundaries of XBL components. But we don't recommend it as it breaks encapsulation.

See also [this forum answer](http://discuss.orbeon.com/Problem-with-get-outer-instance-from-xbl-component-td4658316.html).